# Create scenario like breadcrumb

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Hello, I need to create scenario like breadcrumb in html. 
I have a page which have navigation such as
home --> department --> computer -->semester 1
If i am on computer page then it should give breadcrumb as

home->>department->>computer

but the concept i got is that javascript:

```
function breadcrumbs(home,name){
    sURL = new String; 
    bits =  new Object;
    var x = 0;
    var stop = 0;
    var output = "<b><font color=\"darkgreen\">You are here:\<\/font\></b>                           <a href=\"http\:\/\/"+home+"\">Home</a> \<b\>→\<\/b\>  ";
    sURL = location.href;
    sURL = sURL.slice(8, sURL.length);
    chunkStart = sURL.indexOf("/");
    sURL = sURL.slice(chunkStart+1, sURL.length)
    while(!stop){
        chunkStart = sURL.indexOf("/");
        if (chunkStart != -1){
             bits[x] = sURL.slice(0, chunkStart)
             sURL = sURL.slice(chunkStart + 1, sURL.length);
        } else {
             stop = 1;
        }
        x++;
    }
    for(var i in bits){
        output += "<a href=\"";
        for(y= 1; y < x - i; y++){
              output += "../";
        }
        output += bits[i] + "/\">" + bits[i] + "</a>  \<b\>→\<\/b\>  ";
    }
    document.write(output + name);
}
```

And Html file is:

```
<html>
    <head> 
        <script language="JavaScript" src="crumb.js"></script> 
        <script language="JavaScript">
            <!--                 
            breadcrumbs('www.celtnet.org.uk/info/info.html','Current Page');
            -->
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
    </body>
</html>
```

And it's output is:

```
You are here: Home >> Documents%20and%20Settings >> a >> Desktop >> Current Page
```

But I dont need page name i need the link name on which i click then it should be redirected to the page which it has assigned so can u give me suggetions

Comment: So what you want as output is the actual `<a href="$location1">Location1</a> >> <a href="$location1">Location1</a>`?

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example, I hope it fits your needs.

**crumb.js**

```
/**
 * Create the breadrumbs HTML.
 *
 * @param [Array] crumbs An array containing a list of crumbs the array must be
 *                       sorted according to their hierarchy.
 * @param [String] separator The string that will be used to separate each 
 *                           breadcrumb tag.
 * 
 * @return A string containing the HTML for the breadcrumb.
 */ 
function breadcrumbsHTML(url, separator) {
   var LINK_TEMPLATE = '<a href="{{href}}">{{crumb}}</a>';

   // Here we remove the protocol and obtain the crumbs.
   var crumbs = url.replace(/https?:\/\//g, '').split('/');
   var href= 'http://', html= '', crumb;

   for(var i in crumbs) {
      crumb = crumbs[i]; 

      // if it is the last crumb do not append the '/'
      href += crumb + (i === crumbs.length - 1 ? '' : '/');

      html += LINK_TEMPLATE
        .replace('{{crumb}}', crumb)
        .replace('{{href}}', href);

      if (i < crumbs.length - 1)  
          html += separator;
   }   

   return html;
}

var URL = 'http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14382848/create-scenario-like-breadcrumb';

console.log(breadcrumbsHTML(URL, ' >> '));
```

And you can use it like this:

```
<html>
    <head> 
        <script language="JavaScript" src="crumb.js"></script> 
        <script language="JavaScript">
            <!--                 
            document.getElementById('breadcrumbs').innerHTML = breadcrumbsHTML(location.href, ' >> ');
            -->
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="breadcrumbs"></div>
    </body>
```

As you might noticed I've removed the styling from the breadcrumb link tags, the styling should be applied by using CSS rules that target the elements inside the `#breadcrumbs` div tag.